# Visio 2016 deployment on a Office 365 laptop

Tags: microsoft-office-365, visio

I'm trying to put a volume copy of Visio 2016 on a laptop that has the click to run version of Office. I have been attempting to use the Office Deployment Tool to get the copy of Visio installed, however, I get the "can't install" message.

I am following along as best I can with the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/overview-office-deployment-tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/use-the-office-deployment-tool-to-install-volume-licensed-editions-of-visio-2016

But I absolutely feel like I am missing something fundamental. I have the iso for Visio 2016 on a share, and I have created an xml that has the file path in it.

```
<Configuration ID="3687c731-565e-4474-9e21-dcde4b9bd286">
  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="SemiAnnual" SourcePath="J:\Software - End User\MS Visio\2016 Standard\setup.exe" AllowCdnFallback="TRUE">
    <Product ID="VisioStdXVolume" PIDKEY="NY48V-PPYYH-3F4PX-XJRKJ-W4423">
      <Language ID="en-us" />
      <ExcludeApp ID="Groove" />
    </Product>
  </Add>
  <Property Name="SharedComputerLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="FORCEAPPSHUTDOWN" Value="FALSE" />
  <Property Name="DeviceBasedLicensing" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="SCLCacheOverride" Value="0" />
  <Property Name="AUTOACTIVATE" Value="1" />
  <Updates Enabled="TRUE" />
</Configuration>
```

What am I missing? Even if it seems like something simple.

Followed the Microsoft documentation and used the Office Configuration tool to build a xml

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/overview-office-deployment-tool https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/use-the-office-deployment-tool-to-install-volume-licensed-editions-of-visio-2016